# Sequence contains no elements MVC

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to redirect to another page using a link (route) and Razor. When the user logs in it checks if they have completed a survey. If they haven't finished the survey they are redirected to the 'Continue' view. They can then click on the Continue link, which will take them back to where they left off.

Everything else works, but I cannot redirect from the 'Continue' view to the 'Question' view without getting a 'Sequence contains no elements error'

Razor:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Continue";
}

<h2>Do you want to continue registration</h2>
@Html.ActionLink(
"Continue",
"Question",
"PreRegistration",
new
{
    questionId = 0,
    direction = "Next"
} ,
null
)
```

Here is the action from my controller

```
public ActionResult Question(int? questionId, string direction)
    {
        var a = (from x in db.Progress.ToList() where x.fldUserID == User.Identity.GetUserId() select x);
        var currentPosition = a.FirstOrDefault().fldCurrentQuestionId;
        var registrationCompleted = a.FirstOrDefault().fldRegistrationCompleted;
        var progressId = a.FirstOrDefault().Id;

        var maxPosition = (from x in db.Question select x.Id).ToList().Last();
        var minPosition = (from x in db.Question select x.Id).ToList().First();

        if (!registrationCompleted && direction == "Back")
            if (questionId == null || questionId < minPosition)
            questionId = minPosition;

        if (!registrationCompleted && direction == "Next")
        {
            if (questionId == maxPosition)
                registrationCompleted = true;

            var q = db.Question.Find(questionId);
            var p = db.Progress.Find(progressId);

            var progressModel = new RegistrationViewModel {Questions = q, Progress = p};
            p.fldCurrentQuestionId = questionId.Value;
            p.fldRegistrationCompleted = registrationCompleted;
            p.fldTimeStamp = System.DateTime.Now;
            p.fldUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            db.Progress.AddOrUpdate(p);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View(progressModel);
        }

        return Redirect("/PreRegistration/Completed/");
```

Also I noticed when I hovered over the link on the 'Continue' view, it says `localhost:53329/PreRegistration/Question?questionId=0`, where as I am expecting to see `localhost:53329/PreRegistration/Question/0/Next`

I cannot work out why it says `Sequence contains no elements`I have changed all of my code to FirstOrDefault() as suggested and I still get the error. I also don't understand why the URL is only showing one element/

The first few lines of the error are as follows:

```
 System.Linq.Enumerable.Last(IEnumerable`1 source) +318
 Foodsnap.Controllers.PreRegistrationController.Question(Nullable`1 
 questionId, String direction) +290
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't call `Last()` on a sequence that has no elements, this seems like a pretty obvious error meessage to me?

Comment: Hi David thanks for your reply. If I go straight into the Question view, without using the Continue view, it works perfectly fine. Perhaps I don't understand your response...

Comment: This hs nothing to do with MVC or Razor, ir's just C# and Linq - debug your code.

Comment: So, I got rid of all of the code  and parameters, all that is in the action is `var a =1;` and still it says the same thing. I have also tested all of the LINQ and it works fine as a whole, I also got rid of the last() and used ordering instead. Still the problem persists. I'll do some more research.

Comment: This means there are no db.Questions.  Look at .Any(), .Min() and .Max(). And look at exactly what .ToList() does.

Comment: When an `IEnumerable<T>` is empty, `FirstOrDefault()` and `LastOrDefault()` return `default(T)` from `IEnumerable<T>` - `null` for reference types (classes.) You're using that in some places. But `First()` and `Last()` throw an exception (the one you're getting) if the `IEnumerable<T>` is empty. Look at where you're using `First()` and `Last()`. If the `IEnumerable` might be empty then you have to account for that somehow. You might check `if(db.Question.Any())` first.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had for some reason managed to truncate my table.